# Ignoring capture group in Regex that is used for repeating the patten

Tags: ruby, regex

`/((\w)\2)/` finds repeating letters. I was hoping to avoid the two dimensional array that is produced by ignoring the letter matching second capture group like this: `/((?:\w)\2)/`. It seems that's not possible. Any ideas why?

[Rubular example](http://rubular.com/r/ugAKnZvKxQ)

Comment: Can you add a link to the "recent question" in your question?

Comment: Question stands alone by itself. Don't let the reader refer to another question or another website in order to understand this question. Regex does not return a two dimensional array; in fact, it does not do anything. A method using a regex may return something.

Comment: Thanks @sawa! Will take care from next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need *any* capture groups:

```
str = [*'a+'..'z+', *'A+'..'Z+', *'0+'..'9+', '_+'].join('|')
  #=> "a+|b+| ... |z+|A+|B+| ... |Z+|0+|1+| ... |9+|_+" 

"aaabbcddd".scan(/#{str}/)
  #=> ["aaa", "bb", "c", "ddd"]
```

but if you insist on having one:

```
"aaabbcddd".scan(/(#{str})/).flatten(1)
  #=> ["aaa", "bb", "c", "ddd"]
```

Is this cheating? You did ask if it was *possible*.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you're using [`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan), you can post-process the result to return only the first items [`Enumerable#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
'helloo'.scan(/((\w)\2)/)
# => [["ll", "l"], ["oo", "o"]]

'helloo'.scan(/((\w)\2)/).map { |m| m[0] }
# => ["ll", "oo"]
```